# What's the "default" routing table for in Linux?

Tags: linux, iproute

When I list the routing rules in my Linux desktop, this is what comes up:

```
$ ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

I've used routing rules before to redirect traffic to additional tables, but I've always seen the "default" table there without really knowing what's for. Is it special? Could I add routes (and point routing rules) to it as any other table?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/188590/23721